# Unterschied zwischen "andere" und "anderweitige"

Tags: difference

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern  *andere* und  *anderweitige*

> Ohne Kaffee, Cola oder *anderweitige* Aufpuschmittel kann er nicht durchhalten.
>
> Ohne Kaffee, Cola oder *andere* Aufpuschmittel kann er nicht durchhalten

Comment: Es gibt keinen Unterschied, *anderweitig* soll nur vornehmer/gelehrter/edler wirken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Wort *anderweitig* ist zusammengesetzt aus zwei Teilen:

1. ander
   Bedeutung: »der zweite« im Sinn von »einer von zweien, aber nicht derselbe« (vergleiche mit: »der eine und der andere«)
2. weit(ig)
   »in der Art«, »vergleichbar«
   heute sonst nur mehr in der Form »wert« oder »wertig« in Verwendung

Das Wort bedeutet also »mit etwas anderem vergleichbar« oder »in der Art von etwas anderem«. Kürzer kann man diesen Sachverhalt aber mit den Worten »anders« oder »sonstig« ausdrücken.

Die Wörter *»anderweitig«, »anders«* und *»sonstig«* sind also Synonyme, die genau dasselbe bedeuten. Man könnte deinen Satz daher auch so schreiben:

> Ohne Kaffee, Cola oder *sonstige* Aufpuschmittel kann er nicht durchhalten.